# Mi Yodeya Publications

Tags: discussion, publications

Welcome to

### [Mi Yodeya Publications](http://s.tk/miyodeya)

where you can download free, printable compilations of hand-picked questions and answers from **[Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com)**, the online Jewish Q&A community.

- [**Hagada - Mi Yodeya?**](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/mi-yodeya-publications#1937) - *Real questions and answers that spring from the Passover Seder*
  Our companion to the Passover Hagada, featuring questions practice, lore, and thought spanning the Seder, from preparations to closing.
- [**Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?**](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/mi-yodeya-publications#3708) - *Real questions and answers to enhance your Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur*
  A booklet full of questions about the prayers and practices of Rosh Hashanah, Yom Kippur, and the days in between, great for those windows of  time during the High Holidays when appropriate reading material comes in handy.
- [**Chanukah - Mi Yodeya?**](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/mi-yodeya-publications#3337) - *Real questions and answers to enjoy while your candles burn*
  Eight self-contained, two-sided pages – one theme for each day of Chanukah – full of questions and answers about every aspect of the holiday.
- [**Purim - Mi Yodeya?**](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/mi-yodeya-publications#2013) - *Real questions and answers to share and enjoy on Purim*
  Give your friends the gifts of knowledge and humor on Purim, with our personalizable gift booklet or gift card, both full of serious Purim questions and not-so-serious "Purim Torah" questions.

Enjoy!

[image: Mi Yodeya Publications: Days of Awe]
[image: Purim]
[image: Pesach Hagada]
[image: Chanukah]

Comment: This is the coolest thing in the world... I love it!

Comment: nothing for sukkot?

Comment: @rikitikitembo We [started](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2201/future-sukkot-publication-collect-questions) a project for one, but never yet got past early steps.

Answer (score 11):

## ?הגדה - מי יודע

### Hagada - Mi Yodeya?

*Real questions and answers that spring from the Passover Seder*

[image: "Hagada - Mi Yodeya?" with a seder plate]

**Second Edition - Expanded and Improved!**

---

Three years ago, we put out our first publication, a Hagada supplement full of questions and answers related to the Passover Seder, hand-picked from the thousands of great Jewish Q&As at [Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com). Thousands of seders around the world were enlivened, thanks to people bringing printouts of this booklet.

Today, for Passover 5776, we are proud to present a second edition, significantly expanded and improved. With eleven additional Q&As, [***Hagada - Mi Yodeya?***](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TqzcduQYHTeTZKQlpnOURrRG8/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-Roeho9HhhDMmzzHOo9sTEQ) now covers every step of the Seder, from preparation (**"How can I make an engaging seder?"**) to the closing songs (**"Why does Echad Mi Yodeya stop at 13?"**).

Whether you have seen [*Hagada - Mi Yodeya?*](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TqzcduQYHTeTZKQlpnOURrRG8/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-Roeho9HhhDMmzzHOo9sTEQ) before or not, you should print out this beautiful, new booklet and bring it to your seders. You are sure to find questions that pique your curiosity and answers that you hadn't heard before.

**DOWNLOAD** the PDF [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TqzcduQYHTeTZKQlpnOURrRG8/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-Roeho9HhhDMmzzHOo9sTEQ):

[image: Click here to download "Hagada - Mi Yodeya?" (PDF)]

#### Please share this!

When you print this document out for your own use, we hope you'll consider printing out an extra copy to give to a friend. Why not enhance their Seder, too?

In addition, we'd greatly appreciate it if you'd spread the word about this project. Share it on [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/223001802878/photos/a.10153657276662879.1073741826.223001802878/10153657274132879/?type=3)! Email it to your Bubbie! Review it on Twitter! To make it easier, you can use the short link [s.tk/miyodeya](http://s.tk/miyodeya).

---

We would be very interested to hear any feedback you may have on any aspect of this project. Anything you can tell us to help us make future publications even better would be a much-appreciated gift. Please post feedback [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/feedback-for-hagada-mi-yodeya), or email us at Mi.Yodeya@gmail.com.

Answer (score 9):

### [image: Chanukah - Mi Yodeya? with chanukiyah]

## חנוכה - מי יודע?‏

### Chanukah - Mi Yodeya?

*Real questions and answers to enjoy while your candles burn*

Download and print (double-sided recommended):

[image: Download "Chanukah - Mi Yodeya?"]

---

We are proud to present our third community publication, a collection of questions and answers from [Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com) that you can print out, enjoy, and share on Chanukah.

In this book, we present eight self-contained, two-sided pages – one for each day of Chanukah – full of questions and answers about every aspect of the holiday. In general, we tried to make the front page for each day as accessible to the whole Chanukah-celebrating public as possible, putting more in-depth content on the second page.

---

**Keep the flame going! Share *Chanukah - Mi Yodeya?* with your friends!**

- Bring it to your next Chanukah party or menorah-lighting, and read your favorite questions and answers aloud.
- Print out copies of the whole book and give them out to your friends.
- Print out many copies of one of the two-page sections, and put them in your synagogue, school, or community center for people to pick up.
- Share a link to this page with your friends, so they can download their own copies: **[s.tk/miyodeya](http://s.tk/miyodeya)**

---

We would greatly appreciate your feedback on any aspect of this project. Please visit [this page](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2309/feedback-for-chanukah-mi-yodeya) to leave feedback, or email us at Mi.Yodeya@gmail.com.

---

Finally, if you like *Chanukah - Mi Yodeya?*, you'll love:

- [Chanukah Q&A on Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chanuka) - dozens more online questions and answers about Chanukah
- [*Purim - Mi Yodeya?*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/chanukah-mi-yodeya#2013) - our Purim book, with real information about Purim and some silly stuff, too
- [*Hagada - Mi Yodeya?*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/chanukah-mi-yodeya#1937) - our Hagada supplement, full of great questions and answers about Passover

Answer (score 8):

[image: our purim booklet in a gift bag]

## פורים - מי יודע?‏

### Purim - Mi Yodeya?

*Real questions and answers to share and enjoy on Purim*

---

Download and print any of these PDF files:

[image: Full_Size]
[image: Booklet]
[image: Card]

---

We are proud to present our second community publication, a collection of questions and answers from [Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com) that you can print out and share with your friends on Purim.

<sup>WARNING: Some of the content is very, very silly!</sup>

We are offering PDF files in three different formats:

- [Full Size](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TqzcduQYHTQTlhSHJzeFQ4Slk/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-o4IOS2NVXJoYn89uoke_Nw) prints out on 28 single-sided pages of standard US letter-size paper (well, 27 if you skip the second page, which is blank).
- [Booklet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TqzcduQYHTckJTR2FaczNiVEE/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-eCW5rWPIr5HRmWoXo-pogg) contains all the same content as Full Size, but it's formatted to print out as a foldable booklet. It prints out on 7 double-sided pages.<sup>*</sup>
- [Card](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TqzcduQYHTYzZVUWlnbDVIS2M/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-Y875qeSk43w6Rl7oEtT65Q) has just enough of the full content to whet your friends' appetites, formatted to print out as a foldable card. It prints out on one double-sided page.<sup>*</sup>

  * When printing the Booklet or Card, please make sure to print double-sided, with pages flipping up. Otherwise, some of your pages will come out əlʎʇs-ɯıɹnd. If you have any doubt about how it'll come out, we recommend doing a test print before you do a full run.

  [image: Print Options]

---

**In the spirit of Purim, please share *Purim - Mi Yodeya?* with your friends!**

- Print out a bunch of copies and [put them](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2011/2) in your Mishloach Manot, hand them out in your synagogue, or send them by mail. If you save the files and then open in your favorite PDF reader, you can personalize your gift by typing into the fillable field on the cover:

  [image: Your Name Here]
- Share a link to this page with your friends, so they can download their own copies: **[s.tk/miyodeya](http://s.tk/miyodeya)**

---

We would greatly appreciate your feedback on any aspect of this project. Please visit [this page](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1971/feedback-for-purim-mi-yodeya) to leave feedback, or email us at Mi.Yodeya@gmail.com.

---

Finally, if Purim is here, then Passover is around the corner!
Get ready by downloading your copy of [*Hagada - Mi Yodeya?*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/purim-mi-yodeya#1937).

Answer (score 5):

[image: "Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?" ad display]

## ?ימים נוראים - מי יודע‏

### Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?

*Real questions and answers to enhance your Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur*

[Download and print (double-sided recommended):](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TqzcduQYHTajluSUFrQnNjQm8/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-5gCqh7U4JrC2mn9txorP8g)

[image: Download "Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?"]

---

We are proud to present our fourth community publication, a collection of questions and answers from [Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com) for you to print out, share, and use to enhance your experience of Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur.

---

**Share *Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?* with your friends!**

- Bring it to a Rosh Hashanah meal, and read your favorite questions and answers aloud.
- Print out copies, and give them out to your friends.
- Share a link to this page with your friends, so they can download their own copies: **[s.tk/miyodeya](http://s.tk/miyodeya)**

---

We would greatly appreciate your feedback on any aspect of this project. Please visit [this page](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3707/feedback-for-days-of-awe-mi-yodeya) to leave feedback, or email us at Mi.Yodeya@gmail.com.

---

Finally, if you like *Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?*, you'll love:

- [*Chanukah - Mi Yodeya?*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/#3337) - eight pages of great questions and answers about Chanukah
- [*Purim - Mi Yodeya?*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/#2013) - our Purim book, with real information about Purim and some silly stuff, too
- [*Hagada - Mi Yodeya?*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/#1937) - our Hagada supplement, full of great questions and answers about Passover

---