# Feedback for "Purim - Mi Yodeya?"

Tags: discussion, purim-project

If you downloaded or read "[Purim - Mi Yodeya?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/purim-mi-yodeya)," we would love to hear what you thought of it.

- Are there any improvements you'd suggest?
- Is there anything about it you specifically hope we *don't* change?
- Do you have any interesting stories about using it on Purim?

Anything you can tell us along these lines would be much appreciated. The next time we make a publication like this one, your feedback here will help us make it even better.

If you have participated on [Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com) before, you should be able to post your feedback as an answer to this question. If not, or if you prefer to send it in private, please email Mi.Yodeya@gmail.com.

Comment: Where can it now be downloaded please (if you want comments or even if you don't)?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok, thanks for your enthusiasm! It's in production now, and expected to come out in the week leading up to Purim at http://s.tk/miyodeya . If you want to get involved in the project, take a look at other posts in [meta-tag:mi-yodeya-purim].

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok it's available for download now at the link in Isaac's comment.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Is there any tool/website that anyone can use to fetch the most asked questions on a per-year basis, and compile it into a booklet? Because every year, there are new questions that are added.

Comment: @Moshe I'm not aware of such an automatic tool. Each of the Mi Yodeya Publications is the product of a great deal of human editoreal work, almost all of which could not be done by a machine.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of The *Purim - Mi Yodeya?* card printed in color on card stock, adorning Mishloach Manot:

[image: Mishloach Manot featuring Purim - Mi Yodeya card]