# Shall we do a Chanuka publication? If so, what format?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, chanuka-project

So far, [Mi Yodeya Publications](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/mi-yodeya-publications) include successful editions of:

- A Pesach Hagada companion
- A Purim gift book

**Shall we do a publication for Chanuka 5775?**

Chanuka, like Pesach, is one of the most popularly-known and widely-observed Jewish holidays. I would expect a Mi Yodeya publication for Chanuka to be even more popular than our Purim one was.

As Monica Cellio [pointed out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11304?m=14342874#14342874), if we want to do this for this year, now is the time to get started: "Early because we don't want to wait until Cheshvan to start, but who's going to pay attention in Tishrei?"

**If so, what format should we produce?**

I like how the two publications we've made so far were each suited in certain ways for use on their holidays. The Hagada companion had commentary in the order of the Seder, which facilitated its use at that event. The Purim book had versions that were set up to fit well into a Mishloach Manot package.

So, what would be a good format for Chanuka? What would be the intended use? When, on Chanuka, would people love to have some awesome Chanuka Q&A on paper, in their hands?

Perhaps something octapartite, with one section intended to be used on each night, would be nice.

---

Since, so far, there has been one answer that implies "yes" and none that imply or say "no," I've created a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16377/chanuka-5775-publication) for working on this project.

Comment: In addition to the coolness of the word "octapartite", it's a good idea.

Comment: @Scimonster and MonicaCellio: One of the many reasons I like it around here: the rampant logophilia.

Comment: Octapartite makes me think of [this partying aristocrat octocat](https://octodex.github.com/class-act)

Answer (score 4):

I like the octapartite idea (and the word :-) ).  Maybe we could provide a bit of learning at candle-lighting each night -- something to share with the family either before lighting or after the lighting and singing.  Doing this might call for more "bite-sized" portions than the other projects, but this could take the form of a short Q&A "above the fold" and more below for those who want.

This application would *probably* call for more "why do we...?" and history questions, as compared to detailed halacha or complex theology questions.  I don't know if that's good or bad.

[Followup](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2148/472)

Comment: No reason detailed _halacha_ or complex theology can't also get one in the mood for lighting. . . or is it just me?

Comment: @WAF you, me, probably a few others, but what are the odds of the whole family being into it simultaneously?

Comment: @WAF and MonicaCellio Maybe we'd be able to select one Q&A "rated E for Everyone" for "above the fold" and something more advanced/involved for below. Bonus points if the two can be related, or perhaps easier and harder answers to the same question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses and MonicaCellio Every time I want to agree with someone in comments, I'm haunted by the ghostly admonition to "avoid comments like '+1' and 'thanks'". I hope that metacomment mitigates this one.