# What questions should we use in a Chanuka publication?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, chanuka-project

Suppose we're going to make a Chanuka publication along the lines sketched out [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2118/2), with one page (or leaf or section or whatever) per night of Chanuka, and each page containing:

- a Chanuka-related Q&A that's accessible to wide audiences

and possibly also:

- a related Q&A (or possibly alternative answer to the first Q&A) that's more advanced

**What Q&A should we include?**

Tags to mine include ([h/t](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17364782#17364782) to Monica Cellio and msh210): [chanuka](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chanuka), [menora-chanukia](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/menora-chanukia), [oil](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil), [miracle](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miracle), [hallel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hallel), [al-hanissim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/al-hanissim).

Your answer should include:

- A link to, and the title of, the question that you think could work for wide audiences
- Reference to the answers or answers that you think could work for wide audiences
- (Optional) Guidance about any editing that may be necessary to adapt the chosen content for wide audiences
- (Optional) A description of why you think this Q&A should be included
- (Optional) Link to and title of a related Q&A or additional answer on the same question that required more advanced background

Comment: I suppose we should use the 8 top voted answers.

Comment: Next post: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/proposed-rough-work-schedule-for-chanuka-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 5):

Present these two questions together, perhaps under a title like "Due respect for your menora":

[Can one throw out a Menorah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12183/can-one-throw-out-a-menorah)

[Cleaning chanukia in a bathroom?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13258/cleaning-chanukia-in-a-bathroom)

The questions could be enhanced if we could get permission to republish photos of odd-material menoras, such as the ones linked by HodofHod in the first question.

It should be possible to present the gemara and M"B sources in the answers and their implications in an accessible manner for wide audiences.

The wide audiences side could refer explicitly to the other side (see below) for "more on this" as DoubleAA does in his answer.

Advanced:

[Is there an imperative to have a fancy menorah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22602/is-there-an-imperative-to-have-a-fancy-menorah)

To fill a page and increase the value, the answer could be supplemented with direct quotations and translations of relevant parts of the cited sources.

Given that the two questions listed at the top are about discarding or cleaning a menorah, they may be best-situated on the last day.

Comment: I propose using this for night #8 (unless the "9 days of Chanukah" one makes more sense in that slot).

Answer (score 5):

[What exactly happened on the 25th of Kislev?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22720/what-exactly-happened-on-the-25th-of-kislev)

The question is so simple that it could occur to anyone who has even heard of the holiday at all, but there are nonetheless various interesting answers.

This could be split up so that the more basic answers, sam's and LazerA's go on the Wide side, and the more involved answer, DoubleAA's goes on the Advanced side.

Comment: I propose using this for night #1.

Answer (score 4):

Wide audiences:

[Third blessing on the second night of Channukah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66/third-blessing-on-the-first-night-of-channukah)

Anyone who uses a standard listing of the blessings will notice that one is only said on the first night, so most Chanuka-observers are likely to understand this question, and many may have thought of it themselves. The sole answer is well-sourced and uncovers interesting related laws. Some editing may be necessary to introduce the related laws and to make the question more explicit.

Advanced:

[First time lighting Chanuka candles is on second night](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12720/first-time-lighting-chanuka-candles-is-on-second-night)

The relationship here is strong, since both questions are about starting to light on the second night. (I guess this would be a good pair for the second page!) The question and answers delve interestingly into Chanuka theory. Probably only the top two answers, one well-sourced and the other well-reasoned, should be published, although the third ("al tifrosh") could make for an "interesting suggestion."

Comment: Nice pair.  I would recommend editing the title of the second one to mention that it's about the number of candles.

Comment: I propose using this for night #2.

Answer (score 4):

["m'nora" on Chanuka](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4493/472)

What do we call this thing anyway, and how long has it been that way?

I don't have a companion more-advanced question to propose (anybody, feel free to add one).  One of the answers hints at the question of how long we've had specialized candelabra for Chanukah, versus other ways of producing the requisite number of lights, and as a result I've just asked [how old is the chanukiyah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45097/472), which has gotten a very interesting answer (especially if we can get permission to include pictures).

**Edit:** A comment suggested flipping these, making "how old is the chanukiyah" the "for everybody" question and the terminology question the second part.  I agree with that idea.

Comment: I think it might make sense now to use your question as the A side, and the name question as the B side. If we can enhance GG's answer to your question with pictures, especially if we can get one from the Living Torah Museum, that'd make it quite compelling.

Answer (score 4):

[9 Days of Chanukah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4247/5151)

<s>[Why are there eight days of Chanukah if there were only seven miracles?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3703/5151)</s>

Both questions ask about why there are 8 days of Chanukah.

I'm not sure which one is simpler. They might both be advanced. Answers are also long.

[Why aren't Purim and Channuka considered a violation of לֹא תֹסִפוּ?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15509/) (thanks @IssacMoses!)

Both are about why Chanukah isn't like other holidays.

Comment: I'd be hesitant to publish the second one, since it's such a classic question and has been written about over and over in many other publications, including an entire book dedicated to the question.

Comment: Perhaps davka because it's such a classic would make it publish-worthy?

Comment: It doesn't need the publicity, and it doesn't need our particular treatment thereof, which consists of quoting answers from previous publications.

Comment: "[Why aren't Purim and Channuka considered a violation of לֹא תֹסִפוּ?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15509/)" Could be a good Advanced question on the same theme of "why isn't this holiday like the other holidays? It'd probably need some editing down.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I've added your link into the question.

Answer (score 3):

[What's the best way to make wick-and-oil work for Chanukah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15/whats-the-best-way-to-make-wick-and-oil-work-for-chanukah)

This Q&A offers accessible practical advice that can help the reader set up an effective menora using oil. The answers offer various helpful suggestions.

It could be enhanced with photos showing the products and techniques mentioned.

Advanced (tentative):

[Is one allowed to light a candle which has oil on top and water underneath on Erev Shabbos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34925/is-one-allowed-to-light-an-candle-which-has-oil-on-top-and-water-underneath-on-e)

This is related to the above question because it's also about setting up an oil light (albeit not explicitly a Chanuka one), and one of the answers to the above question recommends a similar setup for Chanuka lights. It delves into an interesting point of practical *halacha*.

Answer (score 3):

[Chanukiyah height restriction and modern architecture?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29217/5151)

Could possibly be presented with [Making Bracha on Channukah Candles in Jail](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22692/5151)

Both focus on irregular places for placing candles.

Answer (score 2):

[Were Haman's possessions hung on a tree?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4519/possessions-on-a-tree-where-hung)

This is an intriguing question that could occur to anyone reading the text of *Ma'oz Tzur*, which is a very popular song, and it got a diverse collection of interesting answers.

The title and body of the question should be edited to make them more clear and readable. msh210's answer could be improved by finding and checking out the additional reference mentioned.

Advanced (tentative):

[Making a Seudah into a "Seudas Mitzvah"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22726/making-a-seudah-into-a-seudas-mitzvah)

Admittedly a bit of a tangent, this Q&A is a deep dive into the technicalities of using praising song (there's the connection) to make a meal into a *mitzva* meal. Both the question and the primary answer require advanced knowledge and contain useful sources. Still, I would edit the question to have less jargon and be more accessible.

Answer (score 1):

[Fighting Wars on Shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12311/fighting-wars-on-shabbat)

Not sure if this is more appropriate for Wide or Advanced, but it's pretty interesting. The question may require a bit more halachic background than the other Wide questions, but it's well-written already so as to be pretty accessible.

Possible tangential companion:

[Shabbat restrictions in the Army](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6222/shabbat-restrictions-in-the-army)

plus

[Can Jews standing naval watches take their shabbat in shifts?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35045/can-jews-standing-naval-watches-take-their-shabbat-in-shifts)

I'd edit down the naval watch question to include less speculation.

Comment: Nice find!  The first is well-written and I think works well on the "wide" side; in addition, in this case we can cast this as "then" and "now", since the first asks about the historical event (plus a bit a little after) and the others ask about modern cases.

Comment: Cool question, but not so Chanukah related.