# Proposed rough project plan for "Chanuka - Mi Yodeya?"

Tags: discussion, chanuka-project

The following is a proposal. Please edit as you see fit or post critiques or alternative schedules as answers.

- <strike>Complete: Collect source Q&A candidates. ([We have 9.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/what-questions-should-we-use-in-a-chanuka-publication))</strike>
- <strike>Complete: Decide on exact contents; are we choosing 8 of the 9? Purely by votes?  (Isru Chanukah to use all 9? :-) ) **Consensus:** drop [this one](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2164/472)</strike>
- <strike>Complete: Produce [style template](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2231/2), [format guideline](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2238/2) (including content/jargon guideline and footnotes), and [calls for edited submissions](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2239/2)</strike>
- <s>Complete: Submit [first draft](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2239/chanuka-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-of-edited-content?cb=1) of edited content</s>
- <s>Complete: [Second-party edits](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2265/chanuka-mi-yodeya-call-for-second-party-content-edits) of first draft for accessibility, sourcing, jargon, etc.</s>
- <s>Complete: Write [introduction](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/chanukah-publication-introduction) and any back-matter</s>
- <s>Complete: Produce first draft of publishable book in MS Word</s>
- <s>Complete: Proofread first draft and produce list of errata</s>
- <s>Complete: Revise Word document to address proofreading results and produce PDF document final draft candidate.</s>
- Due Monday, December 8: Proofread final draft candidate.
- Due Tuesday, December 9: Make any final fixes, produce final document, and put it up on the Internet for distribution
- Tuesday, December 9 - Wednesday, December 24: Promote, promote, promote
- Tuesday, December 16 (night): Chanuka begins

Ongoing discussion of this project is taking place in [a dedicated chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16377/chanuka-5775-publication).

Comment: What kind of format guideline are you talking about?

Comment: @Scimonster like http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1924/472 plus http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1513/472 probably with better-specified footnote styling and stronger accessibility requirements, so we can put all necessary bibliographic and glossaric information in nicely, on the page.

Comment: Looks good to me!  One thing to note is that the small window between the end of the first proofreading (Nov 26) and the revisions from it (Nov 30) includes the Thanksgiving holiday.  Not an issue for some of us, but we should make sure our editor won't be busy, traveling, etc then.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Good point. Putting in revisions isn't nearly as big as job as the initial import and formatting, in my experience, but it is a job that requires some sit-down time. When we identify the first round proofreader[s], we can request faster turnaround than a week, if possible.

Comment: [It's still Wednesday somewhere, right?](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2231/472)

Answer (score 2):

## Submission Template

*This answer contains the template for editing questions.  It's mostly the same as for the last two, except that each submission now contains two Q&As, and the inclusion of footnotes. Please see the [Style Guidelines](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2238/2).*

---

## Day Title

*Provide a title that unifies the two questions. Try to make it sound interesting.*

### 1st Question title?

**Ploni Asker asked<sup>1</sup>:**
*Question body goes here.  Be sure to remove hyperlinks; you can turn them into footnotes<sup>2</sup> or parenthetical comments, or remove them if they're not important enough for a print publication<sup>3</sup>.  Use the regular markdown formatting.  (Hint: if you use the edit link on a question or answer you can cut/paste the original markdown.  Don't save your edit, though -- cancel!)*

*For both questions and answers, feel free to edit for clarity, grammar, tangents, length, etc.*

---

**Reuven Answerer said:** *include the answer best (in your judgment) for this publication.  Keep it focused; if there is tangential information that, while great online, seems like too much here, edit it down.  Identify sources but don't include URLs (here).*

*If other answers cover the same territory but add something small, you can incorporate them with:* **Shimon Answerer added** ... .

**Yitzchak Answerer said:** *if there's a second answer that brings a **different** perspective, include it here.  Try to keep it down to one or two answers, keeping length limits in mind.*

*Feel free to vary the verb -- "answered", "said", "offered an alternative", etc.*

---

1. Original question:  [Title] mi.yodeya.com/q/##### *The first footnote on each question should provide the title (only if significantly different from Question Title, above) and URL of source question, in this form.*
2. *In the text, wrap footnote numbers with the HTML "sup" tag.*
3. *Footnotes can be used for longer explanations of unfamiliar terms, references of sources, and some parenthetical statements.*

---

### Advanced: 2nd Question title?

**Almoni Asker asked<sup>1</sup>:** *The body of the second question goes here. See above.*

---

**Shim'on Answerer said:** *Answer text goes here. See above.*

---

1. Original question:  [Title] mi.yodeya.com/q/##### *Note that footnote numbering restarts for each page, so if you get each question plus answers to be about 400 words and thus its own page, this footnote should always be 1.*

---

Contributors:
*Names and URLs of contributors, in the following form (with two spaces at the end of each entry, to keep them on separate lines). Note that these are for copying and pasting into a credits page, not for inclusion on this page, so one consolidated list for the two questions is good. If you want to be extra helpful, please alphabatize them.*

Almoni mi.yodeya.com/u/###
Ploni mi.yodeya.com/u/###
Reuven mi.yodeya.com/u/###
Shim'on mi.yodeya.com/u/###
Yitzchak mi.yodeya.com/u/###

---

Here's a cheat sheet to cut/paste from:

```
# Day Title #

## 1st Question Title ##

__XXX asked<sup>1</sup>:__ ... 

----------

__XXX said:__ ...

__XXX said:__ ...

----------

1. Original question: [TITLE]  mi.yodeya.com/q/#####  

----------

## Advanced: 2nd Question Title ##

__XXX asked<sup>1</sup>:__ ... 

----------

__XXX said:__ ...

__XXX said:__ ...

----------

1. Original question: [TITLE]  mi.yodeya.com/q/#####  

----------    

Contributors:     
NAME mi.yodeya.com/u/###    
NAME mi.yodeya.com/u/###
```

Comment: Should we use mi.yodeya.com or judaism.stackexchange.com for reference links?

Comment: @Scimonster mi.yodeya.com.  It's what we've used in the past, shorter, and probably more likely to be typed correctly from a paper copy ("stackexchange" being an unfamiliar term to most people).

Answer (score 1):

### Style guidelines:

- **Length**: we're aiming for two pages per day and a day has two questions (usually), so we'll need to be fairly tight. Each page holds about 400 words, so try to make each question plus all of its answers add up to around 400 words, or at least try to make the two questions together add up to around 800 words. Any pictures, of course, cut into this word limit.
- **Accessibility**: The first question and its answers should ideally be intelligible to *virtually anyone who has heard of Chanuka*. Edit aggressively to make this so, including by injecting explanations of concepts. The "advanced" Q&A doesn't need as much injected explanation, but try to make it as accessible as possible, subject to the inherent complexity and depth of the original content.
- **Language and jargon**: Hebrew/Aramaic words and quotations may be in either Hebrew characters (vowelized preferred but not required) or transliterated, according to the transliteration scheme of your (or the original poster's) choice. Transliteration should be used mainly for words  or phrases (as opposed to long quotations) and should be italicized. Either way, a translation into English should be included and set off clearly as such unless the word is commonly used in English discourse. If the original post doesn't live up to the [jargon guideline](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/52/2), fix that here (and feel free to fix it there, too!).
- **Citations** should use a full name of the cited work, using the (reasonable) translation or transliteration of your choice. E.g. "Exodus" "Shemos" and "Sh'mot" are all fine, but not "Ex." If the name used is not English, and there is a commonly-used English alternative, put that into a footnote.
- If the original post doesn't live up to the **[quotation guideline](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/76/2)**, fix that here (and feel free to fix it there, too!).
- **Footnotes**: This publication will not have a stand-alone glossary or bibliography, so all translations and sources must be contained on the page, either in the text or in footnotes.
- All English should comply with standard English **grammar and spelling**.
- Try to preserve the **original poster's tone and voice** (within the bounds of appropriateness and accessibility!).