# "Chanuka - Mi Yodeya" call for second-party content edits

Tags: discussion, chanuka-project

We now have eight days' worth of [edited content](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2239/chanuka-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-of-edited-content) for "[Chanuka - Mi Yodeya?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/shall-we-do-a-chanuka-publication-if-so-what-format)." The next step is to make sure that each of these sections gets a good once-over by someone who didn't do the first edit, to help make sure that the content is high-quality and accessible.

So, please select one (or more!) of the sections that *you did not do the initial editing on*, from the list in the answer post below, and do the following:

- Review the [post template](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2231/2), [style guidelines](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2238/2), and mostly-already-re-edited [first submission](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2240/2).
- Read the entire post, carefully. Check for compliance with the style guidelines, overall quality, readability, and - especially for the first half - accessibility to readers with limited background in Judaism.
- Edit the post *in place* wherever you see a way to improve it.
- Cross it off the list in the answer post here (`<s> ... </s>`).

Let's try to get these done by **Friday, November 14**, so that we have ample time for the next steps in this book production before Chanuka.

Reference links:

- [Rough project plan](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/proposed-rough-project-plan-for-chanuka-mi-yodeya)
- [Project chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16377/chanuka-5775-publication)

Answer (score 3):

These are the sections of edited content that need to be re-edited:

- <s>[Lighting Candles for the First Time on the Second Night](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2240/2)</s>
- <s>[Why is this holiday different?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2247/2)</s>
- <s>[What are we celebrating on this night?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2249/2)</s>
- <s>[Oil - It's Not Just for Latkes](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2252/2)</s>
- <s>[Strange Placement of the Chanukiah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2255/2)</s>
- <s>[Song and Celebration](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2258/2)</s>
- <s>[How special is your menorah?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2260/2)</s>
- <s>[History of the Chanukiah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2264/2)</s>