# Future Sukkot publication: collect questions

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, sukkot-project, question-catalog

Today in chat Isaac [said](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=18035482#18035482), in the midst of a discussion about "how-to" questions:

> I think that in a future year, we should consider publishing a pamphlet and/or online summary of our Sukkot HowTos (both Sukka and Arba Minim). We've got a lot of great stuff in this category.
>   ... This might even be something that would be good to consider updating every year, to take advantage of the latest technology.

Since I made this post, we have [broadened the scope of the project](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3576/5323) to all Sukkot questions.  I think it stands to reason that we also include Sh'mini Atzeret.

That's a great idea that we should come back to later -- but, since we're about to enter Sukkot *this* year and there've been lots of relevant questions recently, I thought I'd start a question-collecting post now.  While you're browsing the site (or *asking* or *answering* these questions), please edit the answers to this question to add links to Sukkot questions that seem worthy of broader publication.  That way, when we come back to this in some future year, we'll already have a head start.

There are two community-wiki answers, one to collect how-to questions and one to collect everything else.  (The how-tos already had a head start and have some sorting, so it seems easier to not try to add the others to that post.)

Comment: We coming back to this?

Comment: @DonielF it seems to be in the middle of the pack on the [publication suggestions page](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3574/472), though it's been a while since we've looked at projects.  I've just bumped the post with an edit; feel free to discuss more there.  As we saw last year, even a suggestion that isn't at the top of the list can be done if somebody decides to champion it.  Are you interested in organizing a Sukkot book?

Comment: Now would be the time to get started on it. I don't know that I can work on the actual publishing, but if all it entails is collecting questions, sure.

Comment: @DonielF each project so far has had a project plan ([example](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2215/472)), which requires someone to drive it.  The main steps are: collect questions, edit for publication, review, and assemble into a document and publish.  The first three of these are community efforts; the last doesn't have to be the organizer (you in this case) but we need to find someone.  The organizer's job is to keep track of everything, help move things along, and (usually) personally participate in the community tasks. Many of the "regulars" hang out in [chat]; talk there?

Answer (score 4):

### How-to questions

**[Sukkah construction](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to+sukkah):**

- [How do I do the car-door-sukkah trick?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2964/5323)
- [What green plants can I use for s'chach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/46113/what-green-plants-can-i-use-for-schach)
- [Plans for building a sukkah shlock](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/46130/plans-for-building-a-sukkah-shlock)
- [Plans for an all-wood sukkah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/plans-for-an-all-wood-sukkah) (maybe, if it gets more answers or a report of successful use)
- [How can i prevent schach from flying off in the wind?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47290/how-can-i-prevent-schach-from-flying-off-in-the-wind)
- [How to select the spot for my Sukkah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56254/759)

**Sukkah use:**

- [What is the best way to keep bugs out of the sukkah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31202/what-is-the-best-way-to-keep-bugs-out-of-the-sukkah)
- [Advice for Lighting in a Sukkah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19096/advice-for-lighting-in-a-sukkah)
- [What do sukkahmobiles use for schach, and how do they keep it fastened?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3073/5323)

**[Arba minim](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lulav-etrog-arba-minim+how-to):**

- [How do you maximize your aravot's period of freshness?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7)
- [Keeping a lulav green and moist](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47263/5323)
- [How to grow your own aravos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47369/5323)

**See also:** [questions tagged `sukkah` and `how-to`](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sukkot+how-to).

Answer (score 2):

### Other Questions

Tags to review: [sukkah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sukkah), [sukkot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sukkot), [hoshana-rabbah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hoshana-rabbah), [shmini-atzeres](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shmini-atzeres), [simchas-torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simchas-torah), [hakhel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hakhel), [lulav-etrog-arba-minim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lulav-etrog-arba-minim), [geshem-tal-ruach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geshem-tal-ruach).  Also, [questions about ushpizin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hachnasat-orchim-guests+sukkot).

**Building the sukkah**

[When can you build the sukkah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10464/when-can-you-build-the-sukkah)
[Is Building a Succah a mitzva?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46212/759)
[Can you build a succah on Sukkot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46186/759)
[Can a Sukkah have all-glass walls?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10639/759)

**Living in the sukkah**

[Eating in sukkah before or after sukkot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10624/eating-in-sukkah-before-or-after-sukkot)
[Putting a mezuzah on a sukkah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77863/759)

**Arba Minim**

[Why do we beat the arava?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20263/759)

**Prayers on the holiday**

[Why doesn't Tefilat Geshem have a verse referring to Miriam?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14298/759)
[Why is Hallel different in Sukkot and Pesach (chol ha-moed)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64267/759)
[Leishev Basukkah before Shehechiyanu or after?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20533/759)

**Beit Hamikdash Practices**

[Source for Simchas Beis HaShoeivah nowadays](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76991/759)

**Miscellaneous Practices**

**Spirit of the Holiday**

[Does the Date of Sukkot Correspond to Any Particular Event?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46089/759)
[What are we "celebrating" on Shmini Etzeres?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20495/759)
[Shavuos Versus Simchas Torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1035/759)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/85498/759 if it gets good answers

Answer (score 1):

### Questions about the Torah readings

List of readings from http://www.jewfaq.org/readings.htm.

**Maftirs and Chol Hamoed**: Num 29:12 - 30:1 [pinchas](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pinchas)

**First Day(s)**: Lev 22:26-23:44   [parashas-emor](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashas-emor)
Haftarot: Zech 14:1-21  [zecharia-book-of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zecharia-book-of), I Kings 8:2-21 [melachim-kings-book-of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/melachim-kings-book-of)

[Why are the commandments for the holiday of Succot interrupted by commandments regarding sacrifices in general?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/58976/759)
[Why were there only two tablets in the ark?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68355/759) with some work

**Intermediate Shabbat**:   Ex 33:12-34:26 [parashat-ki-tisa](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-ki-tisa)
Haftara: Ezek 38:18-39:16 [ezekiel--the-book](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ezekiel--the-book)

[Why is the torah reading for minor fast days different by just one verse from when that reading occurs in the regular cycle?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36571/759) if we can get an answer

**Shemini Atzeret I in Diaspora**:  Deut 14:22-16:17 [parashat-reeh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-reeh)
Haftara: I Kings 8:54-9:1 [melachim-kings-book-of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/melachim-kings-book-of)

[Source for Maaser Money](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59471/759) maybe

**Simchat Torah**: Deut 33:1-34:12 [parashat-vezot-habracha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-vezot-habracha), Gen 1:1-2:3 [parashat-bereishit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-bereishit)
Haftara: Josh 1:1-18 (alt: Josh 1:1-9) [joshua--book-of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joshua--book-of)

["And it was evening, and it was morning, *one* day"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47419/759)
[Let there be light! But from where?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4462/759)
[Why is there no "Vayehi Erev..." for the seventh day?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77296/759)  maybe with some work
[Plants before the Sun in the Order of Creation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33405/472)

Comment: As rich as Genesis 1 is, I'm not sure having 4 or even 3 questions from it is really the appropriate number for this project. We should be focusing more on Sukkot stuff IMO.

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps it would be nice to have a Simchat Torah section including one Q from Vezot and one from Bereishit.