# Days of Awe book: collect links here

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, days-of-awe-project

[This proposal for a high-holy-days book](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3577/472), possibly billed as a machzor companion, suggests the following types of content:

- Q&As related to particular parts of the Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur machzors.
- Q&As related to Halacha and How-tos of Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur.
- Q&As related to ideas about Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur in general, and possibly Teshuva in general.

Our first step, before we can start to prepare material for publication, is to collect links to candidate questions.  Please use the Community Wiki answer here to do this.  We are looking for interesting questions with good answers, especially those featuring our own writing.  See our [past publications](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1568/472) for examples.  While you're looking, please feel free to improve the things you find on the site if you can.  And if you have a question and don't find it, please ask it (so if it gets good answers it can end up in the book).

[Here are some relevant tags](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selichot+or+repentance-teshuvah+or+vayera+or+yom-kippur+or+rosh-hashanah-new-year+or+yonah-jonah-book-of+or+parshat-acharei-mot+or+aseres-yemei-teshuva+or+high-holidays+or+aleinu-leshabeiach) (thanks Isaac).

The categories suggested here are just starting points.  If you think of another category that we should be looking at, edit it into the answer!  At this point we're gathering input to later winnow down into a publication; if you think something is worth including, please link it.

As of Sunday, July 5th, we have enough links here to make a respectable-sized book. Feel free to continue adding links if you find questions that would be worth including.

See also:

- [chat room for discussing this project](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25414/high-holidays-project).
- [Project Plan for "Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?"](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3591/proposed-rough-project-plan-for-high-holidays-publication)
- Call for edited submissions: [Part 1: Machzor, Rosh Hashana](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3610/hhd-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-part-1-machzor-rh), [Part 2: Machzor, Yom Kippur](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3611/hhd-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-part-2-machzor-yk), [Part 3, halacha and how-tos](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3612/hhd-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-part-3-halacha-and-how-tos), [Part 4: themes](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/hhd-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-part-4-themes), [Part 5: Selichot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3642/days-of-awe-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-part-5-selichot).  When you edit a question for submission strike it out on the list in the answer here.  (Don't delete!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please link to (and categorize) candidate questions here.  Feel free to include notes (e.g. to identify particular answers).  If you think something should change in the question or answers, edit it *there* please so that the site, and not just the book, benefits from that improvement.

If a question plausibly fits into a section of the machzor, please include it in that list, even if it fits one of the other lists.

[EDIT LINK FOR CONVENINCE](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3588/edit)

**Questions about the machzor (please sort by section):**

- <s>Intro to Machzor section: [Why is the Machzor called a Machzor?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10469/why-is-the-machzor-called-a-machzor)</s>
- RH, Hataras Nedarim (Annulment of Vows): [Can a convert (ger tzedek) serve on a beis din to annul a non-convert's vows?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2842/can-a-convert-ger-tzedek-serve-on-a-beis-din-to-annul-a-non-converts-vows)
- RH, Hataras Nedarim (Annulment of Vows): [Why do we call the "judges" experts?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52910/why-do-we-call-the-judges-experts)
- <strike>RH/YK, any non-Musaf Amida, Ya'aleh Veyavo: [Kel (Melech) Chanun V'Rachum -- do you say Melech?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/kel-melech-chanun-vrachum-do-you-say-melech/)</strike>
- <s>RH, greeting after Maariv: [Why a formulaic greeting on ליל ראש השנה?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10339/why-a-formulaic-greeting-on-%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C-%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94)</s>
- <s>RH, Simanim (symbolic foods eaten at the evening meal): [Why specifically an apple on Rosh HaShanah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20334/apple-on-rosh-hashanah)</s>
- RH, Simanim (symbolic foods eaten at the evening meal): [Earliest source for dipping apple in honey on Rosh Hashana](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18810/earliest-source-for-dipping-apple-in-honey-on-rosh-hashana)
- <s>RH and YK, P'sukei d'Zimra: [Shochen Ad, HaKail, HaMelech - why?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10478/shochen-ad-hakail-hamelech-why)</s>
- RH/YK/Ten days of Repentence, Kaddish and end of Shmoneh Esrei: [Why do we say עושה השלום during yamim nora'im?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45895/why-do-we-say-%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D-during-yamim-noraim)
- <s>RH/YK/Ten days of Repentence, Avinu Malkeinu: [Avinu Malkeinu - middle verses said out loud by Chazan](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10427/avinu-malkeinu-middle-verses-said-out-loud-by-chazan) (Needs dejargonification to unlock nice content)</s>
- <s>RH/YK, End of Shacharit: [Why don't we say Hallel on Rosh Hashanah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45794/why-dont-we-say-hallel-on-rosh-hashanah)</s>
- RH, Torah reading, 1st day: [Why did Avraham name his son before the Bris (circumcision)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/why-did-avraham-name-his-son-before-the-bris-circumcision) *
- RH, Torah reading, 1st day: [Is there a connection between Hagar's distance and Yishmael's profession?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48221/is-there-a-connection-between-hagars-distance-and-yishmaels-profession)
- <s>RH, Torah reading, 2nd day: [Why was Akeidas Yitzchok a bigger test (Nisayon) for Avraham than for Yitzchok?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11101/why-was-akeidas-yitzchok-a-bigger-test-nisayon-for-avraham-than-for-yitzchok)</s>
- RH, Torah reading, 2nd day: [Wasn't Yishmael already sent away from Avraham's house?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11472/wasnt-yishmael-already-sent-away-from-avrahams-house)
- RH, Torah reading, 2nd day: [Punctuation of Genesis 22:14](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53972/punctuation-of-genesis-2214)
- <s>RH, Haftara, 2nd day or Musaf, Zichronot: [Why Jer. 31 on Rosh Hashana?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20195/why-jer-31-on-rosh-hashana)</s>
- <s>RH, Shofar blowing: [Why is the Shofar sounded on Rosh Hashanah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/111/why-is-the-shofar-sounded-on-rosh-hashanah)</s>
- RH, Shofar blowing: [What should a person think when hearing the shofar?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45125/what-should-a-person-think-when-hearing-the-shofar)
- <s>RH, Shofar blowing: [What is the reason behind blowing the shofar from the side of one's mouth?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45683/what-is-the-reason-behind-blowing-the-shofar-from-the-side-of-ones-mouth)</s>
- <s>RH, Shofar blowing: [What is the origin of the shofar sounds?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9876/what-is-the-origin-of-the-shofar-sounds)</s>
- <s>RH, Shofar blowing: [Yemenite shofar not from sheep](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9878/yemenite-shofar-not-from-sheep)</s>
- RH, Shofar blowing: [Can the full set of 100 shofar blasts be performed by more than 1 person?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45311/can-the-full-set-of-100-shofar-blasts-be-performed-by-more-than-1-person)
- RH, Shofar blowing: [What does "to confuse the Satan" mean and why does it work?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10213/what-does-to-confuse-the-satan-mean-and-why-does-it-work) *(note: [see chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22578693#22578693))* *
- RH and YK, Musaf: [Why by "Ut'shuva, Utefila UItzedaka" does it say "Zom, Kol, Mamon"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20261/why-by-utshuva-utefila-uitzedaka-does-it-say-zom-kol-mamon)
- RH, Musaf, Malchuyot (also YK, Musaf, Aleinu): [Tikkun Olam source](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10366/tikkun-olam-source)
- <s>RH, Musaf, Malchuyot (also YK, Musaf, Aleinu): [How a couple lines in Alenu fit the pattern](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7977/how-a-couple-lines-in-alenu-fit-the-pattern)</s>
- <s>RH, Musaf, Malchuyot: [Significance of "Shema Yisrael"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50409/significance-of-shema-yisrael)</s>
- <s>YK, Kol Nidrei: [What's so moving about Kol Nidrei](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20356/whats-so-moving-about-kol-nidrei)</s>
- YK, Musaf, Avoda: [What did the communal korbanot on Yom Kippur atone for?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27919/what-did-the-communal-korbanot-on-yom-kippur-atone-for) (if the community vets the answer)
- YK, Musaf, Avoda: [On Yom Kippur, why did Chachomim not want the people to know if the red thread had not turned white?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18198/on-yom-kippur-why-did-chachomim-not-want-the-people-to-know-if-the-red-thread-h)
- YK, Musaf, Avoda: [Origin of Mareh Kohen tune](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18414/origin-of-mareh-kohen-tune)
- <s>YK, Mincha, Maftir Yonah: [Why do we read Yona on Yom Kippur?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18691/why-do-we-read-yona-on-yom-kippur)</s>
- <s>YK, Mincha, Maftir Yonah: [Why did Yonah run away?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11510/why-did-yonah-run-away)</s>
- YK, Mincha, Maftir Yonah: [Why doesn't God offer Sodom and Gemorrah the same chance to repent He offers Nineveh?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31491/why-doesnt-god-offer-sodom-and-gemorrah-the-same-chance-to-repent-he-offers-nin)
- <s>YK, Neila: [Is there tashlumin for n'ila?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/is-there-tashlumin-for-nila)</s>
- <s>YK, N'ila: [What does "Baruch shem k'vod malchuso l'olam vaed" mean?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35663/what-does-baruch-shem-kvod-malchuso-lolam-vaed-mean)</s>
- YK, post-Ma'ariv: [Pre existing flame for Havdala after Yom Kippur](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20434/pre-existing-flame-for-havdala-after-yom-kippur)

**Questions about halacha and practical how-tos of the holidays:**

- <s>RH: [Drinking on Rosh HaShanah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20162/drinking-on-rosh-hashanah)</s>
- RH: [Am I allowed to sleep on Rosh HaShanah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20180/am-i-allowed-to-sleep-on-rosh-hashanah)
- <s>YK: [Why are we forbidden to wear leather shoes on Yom Kippur](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30895/why-are-we-forbidden-to-wear-leather-shoes-on-yom-kippur)</s>
- <s>YK: [Wedding Rings on Yom Kippur?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31098/wedding-rings-on-yom-kippur)</s>
- <s>YK: [What is the shiur for anointing on Yom Kippur?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20348/what-is-the-shiur-for-anointing-on-yom-kippur)</s>
- YK: [Is there a justification for the practice not to whip on Erev Yom Kipur?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20396/is-there-a-justification-for-the-practice-not-to-whip-on-erev-yom-kipur)
- YK: [How do I avoid thirst when fasting?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10526/how-do-i-avoid-thirst-when-fasting)
- <s>YK: [Kiddush on Yom Kippur](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5784/kiddush-on-yom-kippur)</s>
- <s>YK: [Benching on yom kipper](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/909/benching-on-yom-kipper)</s>

**Questions about the themes of the holidays, including teshuva:**

- <s>Teshuva: [Do I have to forgive a repeat offender?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10360/do-i-have-to-forgive-a-repeat-offender)</s>
- Teshuva: [Teshuva and non-Jews?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45798/teshuva-and-non-jews)
- <s>Teshuva: [How can someone, halachically, do teshuva when s/he has offended an anonymous person on the internet?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45424/how-can-someone-halachically-do-teshuva-when-s-he-has-offended-an-anonymous-pe)</s>
- <s>Teshuva: [Is the Book of Life ever really sealed?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10392/is-the-book-of-life-ever-really-sealed)</s>
- Teshuva: [Are there unforgiveable sins?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17412/are-there-unforgiveable-sins)
- <s>Teshuva: [What can I do to change myself permanently through the repentance process?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18650/what-can-i-do-to-change-myself-permanently-through-the-repentance-process)</s>
- YK: [Connection Between Purim and Yom Kippur](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55942/connection-between-purim-and-yom-kippur)

**Questions about Selichot:**

- [How "with" the congregation do you have to be in order to say the 13 Divine Attributes (middos)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7783/how-with-the-congregation-do-you-have-to-be-in-order-to-say-the-13-divine-attr) *
- <s>[How can I find meaning in saying selichot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30901/how-can-i-find-meaning-in-saying-selichot)</s>
- <s>[What parts of selichot can be said without a minyan?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18972/what-parts-of-selichot-can-be-said-without-a-minyan)</s>
- ["Poems" in Selichos. Names and structures of Pizmon and Shalmonis. Please explain](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10149/poems-in-selichos-names-and-structures-of-pizmon-and-shalmonis-please-explai) *