# Project Plan for "Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?"

Tags: discussion, days-of-awe-project

The following is a proposal. Please edit as you see fit or post critiques or alternative schedules as answers.

This schedule assumes, tentatively, that a print run and distribution will take place.

- <strike>[Complete](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/high-holy-days-book-collect-links-here) Wednesday, July 1: Post request for links</strike>
- <strike>[Complete](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3597/high-holy-days-book-who-wants-to-help-with-distribution) Due Wednesday, July 1: Post solicitation for non-binding intents to distribute printed copies.</strike>
- <strike>Complete Sunday, July 5: Collect source Q&A candidates [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/high-holy-days-book-collect-links-here).</strike>
- Complete: Due Sunday, July 5: Produce [style template](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3605/2), [format guideline](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3606/2) (including content/jargon guideline and footnotes), and calls for edited submissions: [part 1](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3610/hhd-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-part-1-machzor-rh), [part 2](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3611/hhd-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-part-2-machzor-yk), [part 3](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3612/hhd-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-part-3-halacha-and-how-tos), [part 4](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/hhd-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-part-4-themes), [part 5](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3642/days-of-awe-mi-yodeya-call-for-submissions-part-5-selichot)
- <s>Complete: Due Monday, July 13: Determine the publication's title [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3592/title-for-the-high-holidays-publication)</s>
- <s>[Complete](http://jewcer.com/miyodeya): Due Tuesday, July 14: Create concrete proposal for printing, taking distribution intents and content size into account. Request funding.</s>
- <s>Complete: Due Tuesday, July 14: Submit first draft of edited content</s>
- <s>Complete: Due Wednesday, July 22: [Second-party edits](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/help-edit-days-of-awe-mi-yodeya) of first draft for accessibility, sourcing, jargon, etc.</s>
- <s>Complete: Due Wednesday, July 22: Write [introduction and any back-matter](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3665/days-of-awe-mi-yodeya-front-and-back-matter)</s>
- <s>Complete: Sunday, July 26: Tisha B'Av (observed)</s>
- <s>Complete: Due Wednesday, July 29: Produce first draft of publishable book in MS Word</s>
- <s>Complete: Due Monday, August 3: Proofread first draft and produce list of errata</s>
- <s>Complete: Due Wednesday, August 12: Revise Word document to address proofreading results and produce PDF document final draft candidate.</s>
- <s>Complete: Due Saturday night, August 15: Proofread final draft candidate.</s>
- <s>Complete: Due Sunday, August 16: Make any final fixes, produce final document, and put it up on the Internet for distribution</s>
- <s>Complete: Due Sunday, August 16: Make final decision of how many copies to print</s>
- <s>Complete: Due Sunday, August 16: Send job to printer</s>
- <s>Due Thursday, August 27: Mail printed copies out to distributors</s>
- <s>Due Thursday, September 10: Printed copies in the hands of distributors</s>
- <s>Sunday, September 13 (night): Rosh Hashanna begins</s>
- <s>Some time later: settle accounts and [produce financial report](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3789/472)</s>

Ongoing discussion of this project is taking place in a [dedicated chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25414/high-holidays-project).

Comment: Any discussion/decision on how to allot copies if demand exceeds supply?

Comment: @msh210 I think the going assumption is that we'll choose how pretty and therefore expensive to make the booklet to make supply roughly match demand.

Answer (score 4):

### Style guidelines:

- **Quality**: In general, do what you can to make the final text something you are proud to distribute. Note that just because a Q&A is on the suggestions list does not mean that it needs to be in the final publication. Your first judgement as an editor should be whether this Q&A should be included at all.
- **Accessibility**: Try to make all content as accessible as possible, subject to the inherent complexity and depth of the original content. If this means editing in some explanations of concepts, either in the text itself or in footnotes, fine.
- **Language and jargon**: Hebrew/Aramaic words and quotations may be in either Hebrew characters (vowelized preferred but not required) or transliterated, according to the transliteration scheme of your (or the original poster's) choice. Transliteration should be used mainly for words  or phrases (as opposed to long quotations) and should be italicized. Either way, a translation into English should be included inline and/or in [the glossary](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3666/2), unless the word is commonly used in English discourse. If the original post doesn't live up to the [jargon guideline](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/52/2), fix that here (and feel free to fix it there, too!).
- **Citations** should use a full name of the cited work, using the (reasonable) translation or transliteration of your choice. E.g. "Exodus" "Shemos" and "Sh'mot" are all fine, but not "Ex." If the name used is not English, and there is a commonly-used English alternative, put that into the glossary.
- If the original post doesn't live up to the **[quotation guideline](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/76/2)**, fix that here (and feel free to fix it there, too!).
- **Footnotes**: Use footnotes for source information or notes that are not already contained in the content itself or in the glossary.
- All English should comply with standard English **grammar and spelling**.
- Try to preserve the **original poster's tone and voice** (within the bounds of appropriateness and accessibility!).

Answer (score 3):

## Submission Template

*This answer contains the template for editing questions. Please see the [Style Guidelines](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3606/2).*

---

### Question title, which needn't be identical to the original one on Mi Yodeya?

**Ploni Asker asked:<sup>1</sup>** 
*Question body goes here.  Be sure to remove hyperlinks; you can turn them into footnotes<sup>2</sup> or parenthetical comments, or remove them if they're not important enough for a print publication.<sup>3</sup>  Use the regular markdown formatting.  (Hint: if you use the edit link on a question or answer you can cut/paste the original markdown.  Don't save your edit, though -- cancel!)*

*For both questions and answers, **please** edit for clarity, grammar, tangents, length, etc.*

---

**Reuven Answerer said:** *include the answer best (in your judgment) for this publication.  Keep it focused; if there is tangential information that, while great online, seems like too much here, edit it down.  Identify sources but don't include URLs (here).*

*If other answers cover the same territory but add something small, you can incorporate them with:* **Shimon Answerer added** ... .

**Yitzchak Answerer said:** *if there's a second answer that brings a **different** perspective, include it here. Not every answer posted on Mi Yodeya needs to be incorporated; just include the ones that add useful/interesting information and are sufficiently well-written (after your edits).*

*Feel free to vary the verb -- "answered", "said", "offered an alternative", etc.*

---

1. Original question:  [Title] mi.yodeya.com/q/##### *The first footnote on each question should provide the title (only if significantly different from Question Title, above) and URL of source question, in this form.*
2. *In the text, wrap footnote numbers with the HTML "sup" tag.*
3. *Footnotes can be used for longer explanations of unfamiliar terms, references of sources, and some parenthetical statements.*

---

Contributors:
*Names and URLs of contributors, in the following form (with two spaces at the end of each entry, to keep them on separate lines). Note that these are for copying and pasting into a credits page, not for inclusion on this page, so one consolidated list for the all participants is good. If you want to be extra helpful, please alphabetize them.*

Almoni mi.yodeya.com/u/###
Ploni mi.yodeya.com/u/###
Reuven mi.yodeya.com/u/###
Shim'on mi.yodeya.com/u/###
Yitzchak mi.yodeya.com/u/###

---

Here's a cheat sheet to cut/paste from:

```
## Question Title ##

__XXX asked:<sup>1</sup>__ ... 

----------

__XXX said:__ ...

__XXX said:__ ...

----------

1. Original question: [TITLE]  mi.yodeya.com/q/#####  

----------    

Contributors:     
NAME mi.yodeya.com/u/###    
NAME mi.yodeya.com/u/###
```