# Title for the high holidays publication

Tags: discussion, days-of-awe-project

What should the title for the High Holidays publication be?

For reference, the titles of our previous publications are:

- ?הגדה – מי יודע Hagada - Mi Yodeya?
  Real questions and answers that spring from the Passover Seder
- פורים - מי יודע?‏ Purim - Mi Yodeya?
  Real questions and answers to share and enjoy on Purim
- חנוכה - מי יודע?‏ Chanukah - Mi Yodeya?
  Real questions and answers to enjoy while your candles burn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

?ימים נוראים - מי יודע Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?

Comment: With the subtitle from [this answer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3593/472), or something close to that.

Comment: or: "Real questions and answers about Rosh Hashana and Yom Kipur prayers and practices"

Answer (score 3):

?ימים נוראים - מי יודע
High [[Holidays/Holy Days](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22505195#22505195)] - Mi Yodeya?
Real questions and answers to enhance your Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur

---

^ Based on the others.

Answer (score 0):

?ימי תשובה – מי יודע Days of Repentance - Mi Yodeya?

Alternate translation: Days of Return - Mi Yodeya?

Answer (score -2):

?שנה טובה - מי יודע
The New Year - Mi Yodeya?

Comment: This is really two different suggestions.