# Feedback for "Chanukah - Mi Yodeya?"

Tags: discussion, chanuka-project

If you downloaded or read "[Chanukah - Mi Yodeya?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/chanukah-mi-yodeya)," we would love to hear what you thought of it.

- Are there any improvements you'd suggest?
- Is there anything about it you specifically hope we *don't* change?
- Do you have any interesting stories about using it on Chanukah?

Anything you can tell us along these lines would be much appreciated. The next time we make a publication like this one, your feedback here will help us make it even better.

For that matter, what holiday *should* we do next? We've now done Passover, Purim, and Chanukah.

If you have participated on [Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com) before, you should be able to post your feedback as an answer to this question. If not, or if you prefer to send it in private, please email Mi.Yodeya@gmail.com.

Comment: FWIW, we're already considering doing a [Sukkot publication](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2201/future-sukkot-publication-collect-questions) for next year.

Answer (score 4):

I've received the following comments in email from people I shared this with:

- Thanks, Monica. Scholarly and fun! By the way, I've read but never tried this remedy--that a good way to get wax off anything is to freeze it. I just run hot water over the chanukia for a long time. And it might be hard to fit a whole tablecloth in the freezer...
- Thank you, Monica, for giving me something to think about. Well done. I confess I have never thought of some of these questions.

(And several general "thanks"s.)

Comment: I got a bunch of "thanks"s by email as well, and also [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13258/cleaning-chanukia-in-a-bathroom#comment132874_13258).

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea, but perhaps for something like this (not the Hagadah or Purim books), it could be entirely self-contained. Meaning, we could include the brachot, *haneirot halalu*, and *ma'oz tzur* in the book itself. It would only be an extra two pages, and could be very helpful for people who light candles because of tradition, but don't always do the brachot and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I showed someone the [landing page](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/chanukah-mi-yodeya?lq=1), and he was confused about the comments from previous years (Pesach).
[I did anticipate this.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/16377?m=18935691#18935691)

Also, the title could be a bit bigger and more prominent. ([chat message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19048545#19048545))

---

Other than that, it looks awesome!

Comment: Pesach comment removed. Thanks.