# Halacha l'maase section

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there a way that we could create a section devoted to practical halacha for the express purpose of limmud Torah? This section would not be meant to supplant our policy of CYLOR, but to give someone with limited time to learn after tefillah.

The idea occurred to me this morning after shacharit, when I found many questions in the halacha section wanting in terms of their value for study.

Option 1: Tags

This does present its own problem, at least as far the system presently works, as anyone can apply it.

Option 2: Moderator Selected Question List

This would use halachic questions which have been selected for having a particularly high quality which would be worthwhile for use in Torah study for practical halacha. In other words, selecting questions that a rav could consult, if he so desired, before issuing a p'sak, due to their thoroughness.

Answer (score 4):

Doing something based on tags you already reject based on the issue that anyone can add/remove tags, but there's another. Any tag for this purpose would by definition be a meta-tag, which are discouraged by SE. We have a couple that have been "grandfathered in" ([mi-yodeya-series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series), [purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest)), but creating a new one wouldn't be good.

A moderator-curated set of questions would easily get to be too much work on the mods.

---

Have you considered looking at the [top scored questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha?sort=votes) or [top scored answers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bhalacha%5d%20is%3aa%20score%3a10) in [halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha)? It might not be the same thing that you want, but it is content that the community has deemed valuable.

---

One other thing you could try suggesting. We have done [3 print publications](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568) so far of exemplary Q&A sets on a certain topic (Pesach, Purim, Chanukah). You can suggest that we do another with general halacha, but i would personally be very reluctant to support that, because CYLOR is enough of a problem already -- printing a halacha book wouldn't help that.

---

And if you come across these exemplary questions, so, by all means, upvote them to give them slightly better exposure. You could also create an unofficial list, perhaps by favoriting them, putting a list in your 'about me', or in a meta post.

Comment: I don't think that [purim-torah] is a meta-tag -- it describes the content of a question well.

Comment: Also, you'd want to look for top-voted answers, more so than questions......you might want to try [something like this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhalacha%5D+is%3Aa+score%3A10).

Comment: I added the top answers link, thanks.

Comment: No problem. ....I'm not sure if score 10+ is what the OP is looking for, but it's a start.

Comment: Also, note that the content here is licensed under CC-by-SA, meaning anybody is free to assemble a new collection so long as everything is attributed properly.  (You can't use the logo or represent it as being published *by* Mi Yodeya if it's not, though.)

Comment: Don't forget to follow the twitter account for interesting questions.