# What should we add to "Haggadah - Mi Yodeya?"?

Tags: discussion, haggadah-project

We'd like to [update our Haggadah publication this year](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3923/project-plan-for-haggadah-update), and for that, we need new questions and other improvements! According to my project plan, we should have a list of questions by **Sunday, March 13** in order to progress to the next step.

So, what questions should we add? And also, are there new answers/edits to existing questions that are worthy of inclusion? Or perhaps posts that, upon revisiting, don't really need to be included? Post suggestions for all those here.

The [current version](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/mi-yodeya-publications) ([direct link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TqzcduQYHTT1lpLVM0QVd6Sjg/edit)) is missing questions on the following sections:

- Karpas
- Yachatz
- Maror
- Shulchan Oreich
- [Possibly Tzafun](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20609834#20609834)

Please suggest questions to add to HMY, both in the above sections and in existing ones.

[Here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bpassover%5D%20is%3Aq%20answers%3A1%20score%3A1%20closed%3Ano%20created%3A2013-03-21..2016) is a list of open, answered, upvoted questions in [passover](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passover) that have been asked since H-MY was published.

Ongoing discussion about this project is taking place in a [dedicated chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21835).

(BTW, In the title, one question mark is part of *Hagada - Mi Yodeya?*; the other is a question mark. ;))

Comment: Some suggestions for impovement of the original product are collected at http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/feedback-for-hagada-mi-yodeya

Answer (score 2):

### Karpas

[What does the word “Karpas” mean?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27464/5151)

Simple but interesting question. I'm sure many have wondered what "karpas" is, exactly.

No accepted answer, but one of them has seven votes, which is good enough.

Comment: [First party-edit complete!](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3943/haggadah-mi-yodeya-v2-0-call-for-submissions/3954#3954)

Answer (score 2):

### Yachatz

[How can two contradictory ideas exist in Matzah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37081/5151)

[Suggested by Isaac Moses in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20479763#20479763).

We don't have any "real" Yachatz questions, but this is good enough. It is about matzah. ;)

This one also happens to be particularly suited to Yachatz, because

1. Yachatz is about splitting the matzah in 2 -- 2 ideas in the matzah
2. It mentions *lechem oni* -- we put away matzah for later, as a poor person does

Comment: [First-party edit complete.](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3943/haggadah-mi-yodeya-v2-0-call-for-submissions/3949#3949)

Answer (score 2):

### Nirtzah

[How much is 2 Zuz worth in current USD?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27516/5151)

Whatever random thoughts are floating through your head at the end of the seder. :)

How much is that <s>doggie</s> goatie in the window?

(Ignore my comments here. It's too late at night. :P Just focus on the merit of the question.)

Comment: Also, [this closely related question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16261) was answered in the past year.

Comment: @Fred If you want to include it, please post as a new answer. :)

Comment: @Fred suggested here: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3932/472

Comment: [First-party edit complete](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3961/472).

Answer (score 2):

### Shulchan Oreich

[Hardboiled eggs and salt water at the Seder](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15998/hardboiled-eggs-and-salt-water-at-the-seder)

This is directly about Sh"O, and it has good answers.

Comment: [First-party edit complete](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3962/472).

Answer (score 1):

### Maror

[When do you eat the charoset?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/358/5151)

Charoset is well-known for being part of the tradition of maror. Seems to be an appropriate question.

My only concern is that it has rather low scores (q=3, a=1, a=1) compared to the views (>400). :/

Comment: [First party edit complete.](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3943/haggadah-mi-yodeya-v2-0-call-for-submissions/3970#3970)

Answer (score 1):

### Maror

[Rabban Gamliel says we must mention moror at the seder. Is it just a word association?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56188/5151)

Nice, fleshed out question and answers. It happens to actually be on Maggid, but it focuses on maror, so it's also appropriate to place it here.

Comment: I think it would be better in Maggid.

Comment: [First-party edit complete](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3963/472).

Answer (score 1):

### Magid -- Mah Nishtanah

[When was matzah eaten besides for Pesach? (Chametz u'matza)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27639/5151)

There are already lots of questions in the Magid section, but here's another one. After all, we don't have any for Mah Nishtanah yet!

The question has a score of 6, but the answers are relatively low (all 2 and under). The top answer is by a deleted user -- what would we do about that, credits-wise?

Comment: [First-party edit complete](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3943/haggadah-mi-yodeya-v2-0-call-for-submissions/3971#3971)

Answer (score 1):

### Magid -- In Egypt, they were struck with 50 plagues – ְב ִמ ְצַריִם לָקּו ֲח ִמ ִשים ַמּכֹות

[Why do all of them say that there were 5 times more plagues at the sea, instead of 1.5 times?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56541/5151)

(Disclaimer: It's my own question.) We already have one question in this section, so it could use another. :P

I personally have wondered this every Pesach for the past ~5 years or so. Anyone else?

And besides, i would honestly be really happy to have my own question in print. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Magid -- Mah Nishtanah

[Answers to the Mah Nishtanah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37041/5151)

Seems like a good, common question to include.

I would also recommend including something based on Double AA's answer to [Shelosha - mi yodeya?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22796/5151) -- the (original) questions are answered by Rabban Gamliel.

Comment: [First party edit complete.](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3943/haggadah-mi-yodeya-v2-0-call-for-submissions/3964#3964)

Answer (score 1):

### Magid -- Mah Nishtanah

(Lots of options for this section. :))

[If dipping was common, why does Mah Nishtana suggest otherwise?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45260/5151)

I would definitely edit it at least for here, and probably on the site itself, to include the source texts that are being quoted.

Answer (score 1):

**Nirtzah**

[Chad Gadya: The price of a kid goat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16261/chad-gadya-the-price-of-a-kid-goat)

(Suggested by Fred [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3513/what-should-we-add-to-haggadah-mi-yodeya/3931#comment10464_3519).)

Good question, has one good answer, and goes nicely with the "zuz valuation" question that Fred's comment is on.

Comment: [First-party edit complete](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3981/472).

Answer (score 1):

**Shulchan Oreich**

[What can I feed a vegetarian at my Pesach seder?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27011/what-can-i-feed-a-vegetarian-at-my-pesach-seder)

[This suggestion](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3929/472) made me think of this.

(It's my question and it got some good answers.  We can also incorporate info from the followup blog post on the accepted answer if we want.)

Answer (score 1):

### Tzafun

(I know it's late for suggesting.)

[Why is it ok to pay the kids for the afikoman?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14462/why-is-it-ok-to-pay-the-kids-for-the-afikoman)

This is a good question, but as my [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14462/why-is-it-ok-to-pay-the-kids-for-the-afikoman#comment150763_14462) there says, the answer doesn't 100% answer the question. I would probably include the question, plus the answer as an explanation of the question, but not 100% as the answer itself. Some comments might also be worthy. And then we can invite more answers.

Comment: [First-party edit complete](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3972/472).

Answer (score 0):

### Nirtzah

[Echad Mi Yodeya - why does it stop at 13?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64360/5151)

This question is actually unanswered, but we have [precedent](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3647/5151) for including a prompt question without an answer.

Comment: Could put this on the last page and fill out the page with ideas for 14 and on, one per line, as space permits.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I started a community-wiki post for this [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3982/472); anybody who wants to help, please jump in.

Answer (score 0):

### Shulchan Oreich

[Custom to refrain from eating meat at the Pesach Seder?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/629/5151)

We don't yet have any Shulchan Oreich questions (and it's not so easy to find them). This one seems like a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

### Shulchan Oreich

[If Bal Tashchis and Achila Gasa would get in a fight, who would win?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43971/if-bal-tashchis-and-achila-gasa-would-get-in-a-fight-who-would-win)

This is, admittedly, less topical than [my other suggestion](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3929/5151), but still an interesting meal-related question. The title would have to be changed for the publication though.