# Project plan for Haggadah update

Tags: discussion, haggadah-project

This is my first time as "project manager" for a publication, so if something doesn't look right, please let me know, or fix it yourself. This is a rough project plan for [updating our haggadah](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21835/updated-hagada) supplement. Discussion is happening in the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21835/updated-hagada).

- <s>Monday, March 7: Post request for [links](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3513/what-questions-should-we-add-to-hagada-mi-yodeya)</s>
- <s>Due Sunday, March 13: All Q&A suggestions are in and we decide which to include</s>
- <s>Due Sunday, March 13: Produce [style template](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3941/5151), [format guideline](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3940/5151) (including content/jargon guideline and footnotes), and [calls for edited submissions](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3943/haggadah-mi-yodeya-v2-0-call-for-submissions)</s>
- <s>Due Monday, March 21: Submit first draft of edited content</s>
- <s>Wednesday, March 23: Ta'anit Ester/Erev Purim</s>
- <s>Thursday, March 24: Purim</s>
- <s>Due Thursday, March 31: Second-party edits of first draft for accessibility, sourcing, jargon, etc.</s>
- Due Thursday, March 31: Fill [glossary](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3942/5151) (can be done during first- and second-party editing)
- <s>Due Thursday, March 31: Update introduction to reflect update</s>
- <s>Due Tuesday, April 5: Produce first draft of update in Word [@IsaacMoses, are you available and willing?]</s>
- <s>Shabbat, April 9: Rosh Chodesh Nisan</s>
- <s>Due Sunday, April 10: Feedback on first draft</s>
- <s>Due Wednesday, April 13: Produce final draft</s>
- <s>Due Sunday, April 17: Feedback on final draft</s>
- <s>Due Sunday, April 17: Produce final-final draft</s>
- Sunday, April 17: [Release!](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/hagada-mi-yodeya-second-edition-expanded-and-improved)
- Thursday, April 21: Bedikat Chametz
- Friday, April 22: Erev Pesach
- Shabbat, April 23: Pesach!

Comment: That's just two days for distribution before the Seder(im)? Seems too short to me. (I'm no expert in marketing.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Well, we're not printing and mailing, so it's print on your own, which seems plausible for two days. Though of course if we can get it out sooner that's better. And we can advertise before the finished product is available.

Comment: @Scimonster advertising without a link to the download is going to be of very  limited value. If possible, it'd be best if we can release in time for the Sunday before Pesach, when people will be doing prep but not in the final throes.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Did i perhaps give too much time to the earlier parts and not leave enough for after? From my experience with DOA-MY the first- and second-party edits took a while. But it might be less here because it's not a whole book that we have to edit.

Comment: @Scimonster Probably the best thing is to start from the target date and work back, allotting the time available as best you can. How long community edits take will depend on how much material there is and how many people pitch in. In at least one of our previous publications, not everything that got suggested got edited, and what no one cared to pick up and edit didn't get in. Incidentally, I think that's the closest we've had to a decision process regarding the suggestions, so you don't necessarily need a "we decide which to include" step.

Comment: @Scimonster is there need for any global quality upgrade of H-MY, in light of the quality efforts we've made in subsequent pubs? Does it need global dejargonification? Footnotes/bibliography work? A glossary?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I think updating all of the footnotes/bibliography might be too much work, but we can always make individual suggestions to add. I think a glossary is good, so i included it.

Comment: We should also look through questions that are already in the book to see if, since that publication, there are new or improved answers that we might want to add in.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Isaac already said as much in chat, and i already added as much in the "links" post. :)

Comment: @scimonster sorry, wasn't up to date. Also, thank you for organizing this!

Answer (score 1):

## Submission Template

*This answer contains the template for editing questions. Please see the [Style Guidelines](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3940).*

---

### Question title, which needn't be identical to the original one on Mi Yodeya?

<sup>mi.yodeya.com/q/####</sup>

**Ploni Asker asked:** 
*Question body goes here.  Be sure to remove hyperlinks; you can turn them into footnotes<sup>1</sup> or parenthetical comments, or remove them if they're not important enough for a print publication.<sup>2</sup>  Use the regular markdown formatting.  (Hint: if you use the edit link on a question or answer you can cut/paste the original markdown.  Don't save your edit, though -- cancel!)*

*For both questions and answers, **please** edit for clarity, grammar, tangents, length, etc.*

---

**Reuven Answerer said:** *include the answer best (in your judgment) for this publication.  Keep it focused; if there is tangential information that, while great online, seems like too much here, edit it down.  Identify sources but don't include URLs (here).*

*If other answers cover the same territory but add something small, you can incorporate them with:* **Shimon Answerer added** ... .

**Yitzchak Answerer said:** *if there's a second answer that brings a **different** perspective, include it here. Not every answer posted on Mi Yodeya needs to be incorporated; just include the ones that add useful/interesting information and are sufficiently well-written (after your edits).*

*Feel free to vary the verb -- "answered", "said", "offered an alternative", etc.*

---

1. *In the text, wrap footnote numbers with the HTML "sup" tag.*
2. *Footnotes can be used for longer explanations of unfamiliar terms, references of sources, and some parenthetical statements.*

---

Contributors:
*Names and URLs of contributors, in the following form (with two spaces at the end of each entry, to keep them on separate lines). Note that these are for copying and pasting into a credits page, not for inclusion on this page, so one consolidated list for the all participants is good. If you want to be extra helpful, please alphabetize them.*

Almoni mi.yodeya.com/u/###
Ploni mi.yodeya.com/u/###
Reuven mi.yodeya.com/u/###
Shim'on mi.yodeya.com/u/###
Yitzchak mi.yodeya.com/u/###

---

Here's a cheat sheet to cut/paste from:

```
## Question Title ##
<sup>mi.yodeya.com/q/#####</sup>

__XXX asked:__ ... 

----------

__XXX said:__ ...

__XXX said:__ ...

----------

1. Footnotes?  

----------    

Contributors:     
NAME mi.yodeya.com/u/###    
NAME mi.yodeya.com/u/###
```

Comment: Based on http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3605/5151, but we're not putting the original link in a footnote anymore

Answer (score 0):

### Style guidelines:

- **Quality**: In general, do what you can to make the final text something you are proud to distribute. Note that just because a Q&A is on the [suggestions list](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3513/what-should-we-add-to-haggadah-mi-yodeya) does not mean that it needs to be in the final publication. Your first judgement as an editor should be whether this Q&A should be included at all.
- **Accessibility**: Try to make all content as accessible as possible, subject to the inherent complexity and depth of the original content. If this means editing in some explanations of concepts, either in the text itself or in footnotes, fine.
- **Language and jargon**: Hebrew/Aramaic words and quotations may be in either Hebrew characters (vowelized preferred but not required) or transliterated, according to the transliteration scheme of your (or the original poster's) choice. Transliteration should be used mainly for words  or phrases (as opposed to long quotations) and should be italicized. Either way, a translation into English should be included inline and/or in [the glossary](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3923/project-plan-for-haggadah-update/3942#3942), unless the word is commonly used in English discourse. If the original post doesn't live up to the [jargon guideline](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/52/2), fix that here (and feel free to fix it there, too!).
- **Citations** should use a full name of the cited work, using the (reasonable) translation or transliteration of your choice. E.g. "Exodus" "Shemos" and "Sh'mot" are all fine, but not "Ex." If the name used is not English, and there is a commonly-used English alternative, put that into the glossary.
- If the original post doesn't live up to the **[quotation guideline](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/76/2)**, fix that here (and feel free to fix it there, too!).
- **Footnotes**: Use footnotes for source information or notes that are not already contained in the content itself or in the glossary.
- All English should comply with standard English **grammar and spelling**.
- Try to preserve the **original poster's tone and voice** (within the bounds of appropriateness and accessibility!).

Comment: Copied from http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3606/5151

Answer (score 0):

## Glossary

The glossary should contain translations of all non-English terms that some of our readers may not be familiar with. It should also contain basic biographical and/or bibliographical information about all authorities quoted.

You can look at the glossaries for *Purim - Mi Yodeya?* and *Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?* [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3665/days-of-awe-mi-yodeya-front-and-back-matter/3666#3666). Feel free to copy, paste, and adapt. The [Mi Yodeya Glossary](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/mi-yodeya-glossary) may also be helpful.

Please try to keep entries concise, preferably to one printed line, and no more than two. To help gauge line length, note that the entry for "Bigthan and Teresh" took almost exactly one line, and the entry for "Parashas Zachor" took almost exactly two. You can also look at the preview of this post -- assuming default fonts and sizes, each line is nearly exactly the same size as a printed line. Please do not try to account for every possible alternative transliteration of each term.

---

*add items here*