# Help edit "Haggadah - Mi Yodeya?" v2.0

Tags: discussion, haggadah-project

So far 9 questions' worth of edited content have been submitted for *[Haggadah - Mi Yodeya?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3923/project-plan-for-haggadah-update).* (If we're doing well here, we can even add more.) The next step is to make sure that each of these submissions gets a good once-over by someone who didn't do the first edit, to help make sure that the content is high-quality and accessible.

So, please select one (or more!) of the submissions that *you did not do the initial editing on*, from the lists in the posts linked below, and do the following:

- Review the [style guidelines](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3940/5151).
- Read the entire post, carefully. Check for compliance with the style guidelines, overall quality, readability, and accessibility to readers with limited background in Judaism.
- Edit the post *in place* wherever you see a way to improve it.
- For any non-English terms, names of authorities cited, and names of books cited that not all of our readers will be familiar with, add an entry to the [Glossary](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3942/5151), if there isn't one already.
- Post a comment to the post you edited, saying `SECOND-PARTY EDIT COMPLETE`.
- Edit this post to strike out the edited post (`<s> ... </s>`), so that others can tell where there is work left to be done.

Let's try to get these done by **Thursday, March 31**, so that we have  time for the next steps in this production before Pesach.

Reference links:

- [Rough project plan](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3923/project-plan-for-haggadah-update)
- [Project chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21835/updated-hagada)

> - <s>[Hardboiled eggs and salt water at the Seder?](/a/3962) (originally done by Monica Cellio)</s>
> - <s>[How can two contradictory ideas exist in Matzah?](/a/3949) (originally done by Scimonster)</s>
> - <s>[When was matzah eaten besides for Pesach?](/a/3971) (originally done by Scimonster)</s>
> - [Answers to the Mah Nishtanah](/a/3964) (originally done by Scimonster)
> - [Why is it ok to pay the kids for the afikoman?](/a/3972) (originally done by Monica Cellio)
> - <s>[What does the word “Karpas” mean?](/a/3954) (originally done by Scimonster)</s>
> - [How much is 2 *Zuz* worth in current US Dollars?](/a/3961) (originally done by Monica Cellio)
> - <s>[Rabban Gamliel says we must mention *moror* at the seder. Is it just a word association?](/a/3963) (originally done by Monica Cellio)</s>
> - <s>[When do you eat the charoset?](/a/3970) (originally done by Scimonster)</s>
> - [Chad Gadya: the price of a kid goat](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3981/472) (originally done by Monica Cellio)

Also, not ready for edits yet but still taking submissions: [Why does "Echad Mi Yodeya" stop at 13?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3982/472) (community wiki).

Comment: Text stolen from http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/help-edit-days-of-awe-mi-yodeya. List from [script i wrote back then](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/25414?m=22824229#22824229).