# Final Accounting for "Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?"

Tags: discussion, days-of-awe-project

Here are the final public accounting numbers for the [*Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3708/2) printing and distribution [project](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/and-revision-and-houses-of-prayer-and-tzedaka-distribute-the-goodness-of-mi-y).

**Accomplished:**

We produced over [1400 copies](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3726/2) of the booklet and mailed or otherwise delivered nearly all of them to volunteer distributors around the United States (plus one in Israel) to be put out for people to pick up in over 30 different congregations and other institutions. People [liked](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3707/feedback-for-days-of-awe-mi-yodeya) the publication.

We also produced and sent out donor rewards, consisting of a copy of this publication or a set of copies of all of our [publications](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/) to date, to those who made contributions above certain thresholds.

**Revenues:**

- $1000 - [Challenge grant](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/how-shall-we-fund-days-of-awe-mi-yodeya) from Stack Overflow, Inc. (Paid to Isaac Moses)
- $684 - Community donations, [via Jewcer](http://jewcer.com/project/help-publish-days-of-awe-mi-yodeya) (Paid to Monica Cellio, less fees, below)

Total: $1684

**Costs:**

- $1214.53 - Printing at Staples (Paid by Isaac Moses)
- $312.50 - Mailing via USPS (Paid by Isaac Moses)
- $68.80 - Printing in Israel (Paid by Scimonster)
- $21.42 - Packing and mailing supplies (Paid by Isaac Moses)
- $8 - Credit card payment fees via Jewcer (Deducted from Jewcer revenues) -- this number is so low because the vast majority of donors chose to cover the payment fees so we didn't have to

Total: 1625.25

**Disposition of funds:**

- Isaac Moses provided receipts for all but one (less than 1% of the total) of his expense items for review by the Mi Yodeya moderation team.
- Scimonster provided the receipt for his expense for review by the Mi Yodeya moderation team.
- The Stack Overflow grant of $1000 was paid directly to Isaac Moses, covering most of the costs of United States printing and distribution, which he had expended.
- Monica Cellio reimbursed Isaac Moses $548.45, covering the balance of his expenses.
- Monica Cellio reimbursed Scimonster $68.80, covering his expense.
- Monica Cellio donated the remaining funds, $58.75, to HebrewBooks and Sefaria on the Mi Yodeya community's behalf, rounding up to $30 for each.  Receipts for these donations have been received and shared with the moderation team and Isaac.

Comment: Thank you Isaac and Monica for doing all this work!

Comment: @DoubleAA It was a very rewarding experience. Thanks to Scimonster, too, for bringing our publication to the Holy Land, and to the many people who contributed and edited the content.

Comment: We have received an offer from Sefaria to share our book on their site.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, if they want to archive our PDFs on their site, I can't imagine any objection from here.

Comment: And if they want to do it properly and link the sources, that would be amazing. @Monica and Isaac

Comment: @IsaacMoses So long as they retain the relevant SE attributions.

Comment: @DoubleAA, they'd have to strip out the Credits page to avoid that.